# should I include the @ when using SqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue?

Tags: c#, .net, database, parameters

I have always included the at sign in the parameter name when using AddWithValue, but I just noticed some code written by someone else that doesn't use it. Is one way more correct than the other?

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ixCustomer", ixCustomer);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ixCustomer", ixCustomer);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, both are equivalent in the end. I personally tend to use the notation with the `@` sign myself, to be consistent with the T-SQL code for stored proc I write.

But as far as I know, both methods are fine for .NET apps interfacing with SQL Server.